# How to install a HSIA modem (EC156) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, networking

How can I enable a EC156 HSIA modem for internet connection through Tata Photon Plus plan on my Ubuntu 12.04 system (32 bit)

Comment: Question: Tata Photon is your ISP (Internet service provider ) right?  Did Tata Photon supply you with the modem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and I ended up at the following [**post**](http://smashingweb.info/tata-photon-plus-huawei-ec156-modem-in-ubuntu-fedora/).

However, when I followed the command sequence per this post, I did not use the modem identifier the author has used (1505), instead I used 140b (because that is the value that was reported by `lsusb`; my output said 12d1:140b). I used 140b wherever the author of this post says 1505.

The `sudo usb_modeswitch -I -W -c 12d1:140b` command succeeded in identifying the modem and sending a message through the device.

Hope that helps.